# Browser screenshot using python selenium webdiver + phantomjs for a session managed page

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I am trying to capture the output on browser as an image. The below piece of code works fine

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
driver.get('http://google.com')
driver.save_screenshot('screen.png')
```

But my html pages are managed under a browser session, So I need to capture the output for a session managed page.
Tried supplying session parameters in the url itself for

```
driver.get()
```

But was not successful.

Is there a way possible to bypass the session.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can probably copy the cookies from your "headful" browser and set them it the code, but the cleaner solution would be write the log in procedure in the code.